# menu is not showing for non admin

Tags: routes

I have facing this issue like I have given menu link say http://localhost/mcs/admin/config/b_creation  but that menu only admin can able to access not any other users, all most all the menu which comes under http://localhost/mcs/admin/config/ will not show to authenticated user I have tried many times by setting the permission in people->permission but no use of it it shows

> Access denied You are not authorized to access this page

. can any one tell me why is it happening?

Comment: Are the nodes published? Do anonymous users have the right to access menus? What are the block settings?

Comment: @Scorpid: I have given all permission but still its not appearing for non admin

Comment: Are the nodes connected to the menu-items permitted for anonymous users?

Comment: its a setting page which comes under configuration I,e admin->configuration->setting page. and I have enabled all the permission for authenticated people in permission page I am wondering that what could be the reason for this.

Comment: Okay, since you are using the admin path, the system will use the admin theme. Check how the blocks are set in the admin theme...

Comment: @Scorpid:Check how the blocks are set in the admin theme.? means do I need to check in theme or blocks?sorry if I am asking silly question

Comment: No problem, each theme can have seperate block settings. Meaning blocks in other regions. Go to structure > blocks and select your admin theme. Most probably the blocks are not set right...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to manage permissions in the following area,

- Goto Structure->Menus->Management
- Under Administration->Configuration->b_creation
- Click Edit link
- At the bottom check the roles you need to grant access and Save

But make sure this has security issues, give the permissions to trusted users only.

Comment: I have set all permission but its of no use

Comment: •Goto Structure->Menus->Management ->I understood  , but •Under Administration->Configuration->b_creation this one will I get on management page please  be more clear

Comment: I meant, administration->configuration->b_creation could be the hierarchy in the management page. In the management page, if you go down the page till you see your link item "b_creation" then click edit link. And set permissions for your individual roles.

Comment: I have set the permission for all still its not showing